# Postgresql and Hardware

Tags: hardware, postgresql

Just a question about your Postgresql server(s). On what hardware are you running Postgresql?
(CPU, Memory, Disk configuration, RAID...)

I'm planning to buy a dedicaded server for my postgresql instance:
- Dell R710
- Xeon E5520 x 1
- RAM: 24GB 
- 2x146GB SAS 15K RAID1 for OS + pg_xlog
- 3x450 SAS 15K RAID5 OR 4x450GB SAS 15K RAID10 for database.

What do you think about this config?

Thank You!

Comment: why only one CPU?

Comment: 1 Xeon E5520 Quad Core is not enough to you?

Comment: This question cannot be adequately answered without details on what kind of workload you expect. How many databases? How large are they? Transactions per second? Write-heavy? Read-heavy? What kind of data is stored (ie, binary, text, etc)? The more details you can provide, the more useful your answers will be.

Comment: ok, I understand. I'll work to give more informations. Sorry for this.

Comment: @Pol - I'd want to max the CPU utilization on my mainboard, personally - adding one later is harder than adding mroe RAM, for example :)

Answer (score 4):

That system looks pretty good. Unless your load is read-only, you will likely first bottleneck on I/O. Avoid RAID5, go for RAID10.

Also, make sure you have plenty of *battery backed* cache memory on the RAID controller. That'll make a huge difference in write performance.

Comment: bump for RAID 10, excellent choice in terms of speed/capacity/redundancy trade-offs.

Answer (score 2):

Database server hardware is dependent on what you will be doing with it. You need to at least take a guess at your load (database size, transactions per hour, etc, etc) before you can properly spec your servers.

For instance, I run a postgresql database as part of an embedded system on a 1Ghz, single-core CPU with a 2Gig flash card for an HD and only 512megs of memory. Clearly this won't handle any kind of large loads, but for what we're doing it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The only Postgre server we have is our HP Command View server as it insists on using Postgre (has no MSSQL or Oracle option). It's a HP BL460c G6 with dual Xeon E5540's, 12GB DDR3 and dual 146GB 6G SAS SFF disks running W2K3 EE 32-bit with an Emulex 4Gbps FC mezz HBA. It runs just fine.